# Using multiple github accounts with ssh keys, works only first try on each account

Tags: ssh, ventura, macos, git

Following different pages I ended up with a `~/.ssh/config` looking like this:

```
Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/one_key

Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/two_key

Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

It works fine but only on the first try on each repo after login. For example:

1. Login
2. Execute `git pull` on a repo with ssh one_key. Successful.
3. Execute `git pull` on a repo with ssh two_key. Failed.

   ERROR: Repository not found.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.

Need to logout

4. Login
5. Execute `git pull` on a repo with ssh two_key. Successful.
6. Execute `git pull` on a repo with ssh one_key. Failed.

   ERROR: Repository not found.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.

I can't get both of the keys working without logging out. Both are private repositories.

I'm using macOS Ventura 13.2 with M2.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is this a problem with git or ssh?  Can you post the exact error you received rather than “failed?”

Comment: Edited adding the error message. My guess is that it has to do with macos config because i have the same ssh config on my linux distro without the UseKeychain and AddKeysToAgent params and works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I was missing `IdentitiesOnly yes`. My final config looks like this:

```
Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_imp
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```